# No match found in simple regex

Tags: java, regex

Given a token in the format "word_suffix", I want to match and capture the "suffix" part.

For instance, in "Peter_NNP" I want to capture "NNP". I wrote:

```
        String p="Peter_NNP";
        Matcher matcher=Pattern.compile(".+_(.*\\s)").matcher(p);
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

instead of printing "NNP" as I would expect, it arises the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Unknown Source)
```

Note that "word" and "suffix" part can be made of any character.

Comment: Why you used `\\s`, since there isn't a space character?

Comment: Doesn't \\s match also for line terminators?

Comment: I didn't find any newline or carriage return character in your input.

Comment: Yes, you are right, this is because I simplified the thing when posting here. For me each "p" is a token from a sentence, then it makes sense.. if i want to find various matchings like that along a tagged sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `find()` to grab your match group. Also, your capture group expects that there should be whitespace at the end of the string, in "Peter_NNP" there is none, `.*` is enough here.

```
String s  = "Peter_NNP";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".+_(.*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(1)); //=> "NNP"
}
```

But, I would think a simple split would be fine here:

```
String s = "Peter_NNP";
String[] parts = s.split("_");
System.out.println(parts[1]);    //=> "NNP"
```

Comment: i tried   Matcher matcher=Pattern.compile(".*?_(.*)").matcher(s); but it does not work. I am not sure why ?

Comment: As I stated in my answer, `^^^`

Comment: Thanks. But i am not sure what .+ means in your answer ? I believe it means any character one or more time ?

Comment: Its not mine question :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add on hwnd answer, If you want to capture anything after first underscore(even if there is no character before underscore). Thanks hwnd for making me understand this.

```
            String s="_NNP";
            Matcher matcher=Pattern.compile(".*?_(.*)").matcher(s);
            while (matcher.find()) {
                System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
              }
```